# AWS Lambda Task timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have create a one function and sent mail to users but it time out

```
05:48:54
END RequestId: 3508fc6c-29cb-442b-95dd-c963018ca5f3

05:48:54
REPORT RequestId: 3508fc6c-29cb-442b-95dd-c963018ca5f3  Duration: 900083.68 ms  Billed Duration: 900000 ms Memory Size: 256 MB  Max Memory Used: 43 MB

05:48:54
2019-06-25T05:48:54.532Z 3508fc6c-29cb-442b-95dd-c963018ca5f3 Task timed out after 900.08 seconds
```

I have set TimeoutInfo 15 min.

Comment: Your task take more than 15 minutes.

Comment: what's the task? interacting with RDS?

Comment: You will need to add additional debugging information (eg `print` statements) to determine what is taking so long in your function. If the function requires more than 15 minutes to execute, then AWS Lambda probably isn't a good choice for running it.

Answer (score 3):

Another potential issue might be that you have an active connection, so the aws lambda is not responding until the connection terminates.

> callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop – Set to false to send the response
>   right away when the callback executes, instead of waiting for the
>   Node.js event loop to be empty. If this is false, any outstanding
>   events continue to run during the next invocation.

If this is the case, you can set `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` to make callback response immediately by

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

[Official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the timeout set in configuration file 
Also check for VPC!

"Error handling for a given event source depends on how Lambda is invoked. Amazon CloudWatch Events is configured to invoke a Lambda function asynchronously."

"Asynchronous invocation – Asynchronous events are queued before being used to invoke the Lambda function. If AWS Lambda is unable to fully process the event, it will automatically retry the invocation twice, with delays between retries."

So the retry should happen in this case. Not sure what was wrong with your lambda function ,  just delete and created again and may works!

Comment: configuration file ? where it is

Comment: Check for timeout

Comment: timeout is  15 min

Comment: Basic settings,  timeout 15 min and Memory 256 MB

Comment: With this config when i send demo mail then it is working and with clode watch event it is timeout why

Comment: this can happen when querying logs over too wide a block range.